# Rails - Why not use @ symbol in model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

New to rails. I'm having trouble understanding why I use `score > 50` and not `@score > 50` i nthe following example? Doesn't the `@` sign imply an instance variable, which is what I should use in classes?

Where is the class getting the `score` variable from? I was under the impression that it would be considered local if it's not prefixed with an `@` ?

```
class HighScore < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :game, :score
  validate :verify_inputs

  def verify_inputs

    # Why is this line not @score > 50??
    if score > 50
      errors.add( :score, 'Custom error message. Score cannot be more than 50' )
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is the class getting the score variable from?

First of all, since there's no local variable `score`, then it's a method `score`. There must be a column `score` in corresponding DB table. ActiveRecord reads the schema and creates getter and setter methods for every column (dynamically, at runtime). Try this:

```
HighScore.new.methods
```

You should see there two methods, `score` and `score=`.

> Doesn't the @ sign imply an instance variable

Yes, it does signify a local variable

> which is what I should use in classes

Not necessarily. Most of the times, you should use accessor methods. That's what they are for.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, there is a score column in the database. So are you saying that the `score` used in my example is actually referring to a getter method called `score` and not a local variable?

Comment: Yes, you are calling a getter method.

Comment: @Ricky: yes, that's what I was saying.

Comment: @Ricky: **but**, if you were to define a local variable `score` (by assigning to it), then it would shadow your accessor methods. I've been bitten by this a couple of times.

Comment: @Sergio, yes, in fact you have to be very within an ActiveRecord method not to assign an attribute with a "setter", but use the 'self' modifier: `self.my_attr = value` to be sure it doesn't create a new local variable `my_attr`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use @ when you need to access that variable outside of the method, but in your case score is an model attribute I think and that's why it is without @.

Answer (score 1):

`attr_accessor :score` is effectively

```
def score
  @score
end

def score=(value)
  @score = value
end
```

so you could use @score, but you can't without a lot of foolish messing about access `@score` outside of the class as in `myHighScore.@score`.

Comment: `attr_accessor` != `attr_accessible`.